# update-rc.d process output to symlink file

Tags: symlink

I have a script `/etc/init.d/script.sh` configured with `update-rc.d` to run on startup, which it does ok.  It contains line:

```
python pathto/script.py >> /home/sd/log.txt 2>&1
```

The script runs fine but its output isn't recorded as intended, which is in a symlink folder linking to an SD card.  The line does output as intended when executed manually.  Any idea how to get `update-rc.d` to behave?

Comment: is the SD card mounted at the time that your init.d script is run?  if not, make sure that it is (e.g. by mounting the SD card in the script, or changing the priority of your script so that it runs after the mount)

Comment: Well spotted. When I umount the SD I can see the log file that is receiving output. Your suggestion to mount in the script works

Comment: Want the solution tick @cas or shall I delete it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the SD card is not mounted at the time that your init.d script is run.

If that's the case, make sure that it is mounted (e.g. by mounting the SD card in the script, or by changing the priority of your script with `update-rc.d` so that it runs after the mount).